# CASE WHEN shows error

Tags: sql, sas

Im using Microsoft SQL Management Studio and im trying to use CASE WHEN. Here is my problem, my code as below:

```
SELECT CASE  WHEN INCIDENT_RK = 52377
THEN  CASE_RK = NULL
ELSE CASE_RK
END
)
FROM ABC    ;
```

What I want to do is, when INCIDENT_RK is 52377, then set CASE_RK to NULL else follow back the original CASE_RK.

It should be pretty straight forward, however, there are red underlines under INCIDENT_RK, =, ELSE,)
I find it weird cause I did a CASE WHEN Earlier today and it is working fine.
Below is the working code:

```
CASE WHEN CASE_RK NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 2               
        THEN CASE_RK+75961              
        ELSE CASE_RK                
        END             
        )       
FROM ABC
```

Need your advice

EDIT 2:
I Also tried the following code but still no luck:

```
CASE WHEN INCIDENT_RK = '52080'             
        THEN NULL               
        ELSE CASE_RK                
        END AS CASE_RK  

        )       
FROM ABC
```

EDIT 3: I Tried this code.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN INCIDENT_RK = 52080 THEN NULL ELSE CASE_RK END AS CASE_RK  FROM ABC
```

Finally can execute. However, I only have 1 row of INCIDENT_RK = 100 but there are more than 50 CASE_RK is set to NULL

Comment: Remove that unwanted *close parenthesis*

Comment: I Tried this code:
SELECT CASE WHEN INCIDENT_RK = 52080   
        THEN NULL    
        ELSE CASE_RK    
        END AS CASE_RK 
FROM ABC    
Finally can execute. However, I only have 1 row of INCIDENT_RK = 100 but there are more than 50 CASE_RK is set to NULL. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your case syntax looks to be incorrect.

A case returns a statement, it doesn't assign the statement.
Notice the difference between your example that works and the one that doesn't is that in the one that doesn't you try to assign `CASE_RK = NULL`

So depending on the rest of the code of your query it should be something along the line of:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN INCIDENT_RK = 52377
  THEN  NULL
  ELSE CASE_RK
END AS CASE_RK    
FROM ABC
```

Comment: I Tried this code:
SELECT CASE WHEN INCIDENT_RK = 52080   
        THEN NULL    
        ELSE CASE_RK    
        END AS CASE_RK 
FROM ABC    
Finally can execute. However, I only have 1 row of INCIDENT_RK = 100 but there are more than 50 CASE_RK is set to NULL. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Removed the close braces,

```
SELECT CASE  WHEN INCIDENT_RK = 52377
THEN  CASE_RK = NULL
ELSE CASE_RK
END
FROM ABC;
```

Comment: I Tried this code:
SELECT CASE WHEN INCIDENT_RK = 52080   
        THEN NULL    
        ELSE CASE_RK    
        END AS CASE_RK 
FROM ABC    
Finally can execute. However, I only have 1 row of INCIDENT_RK = 100 but there are more than 50 CASE_RK is set to NULL. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you have multiple conditions, separate them using One "Case when" with multiple "Then" conditions. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You has some invalid braces. You also don't want to set CASE_RK to NULL, you just want to show NULL.

```
SELECT CASE_RK = CASE WHEN INCIDENT_RK = 52377
   THEN  NULL
   ELSE CASE_RK
END
FROM ABC;
```

Comment: I Tried this code:
SELECT CASE WHEN INCIDENT_RK = 52080   
        THEN NULL    
        ELSE CASE_RK    
        END AS CASE_RK 
FROM ABC    
Finally can execute. However, I only have 1 row of INCIDENT_RK = 100 but there are more than 50 CASE_RK is set to NULL. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems incorrect syntax in your query. You need to remove the close braces from your query. Please try the below query:

```
SELECT CASE  WHEN INCIDENT_RK = 52377
THEN  CASE_RK = NULL
ELSE CASE_RK
END
FROM ABC;
```