# CASE WHEN getting the wrong results

Tags: sql, sas

im using CASE WHEN to read data before updating it(later on, once my select CASE WHEN is fully functional)
However, im not getting the right result.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN INCIDENT_RK = 52080 
        THEN NULL
        ELSE CASE_RK
        END AS CASE_RK

FROM [casemgmt4].[ecmdb4].[INCIDENT_LIVE]
```

[Just one record with the same SELECT statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It3Az.png)

However, it makes more than 120 rows to NULL
[More than 120 records with the same SELECT statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjjJ2.png)

Can anyone tell me if I have mistake in code?

Comment: syntax should be 
SELECT CASE  INCIDENT_RK  
         WHEN 52080 
         THEN NULL
         ELSE CASE_RK
        END AS CASE_RK

Comment: if I use your code, the '=' will have red underline and it says "incorrect syntax near '='"

Comment: @an33sh - Eh? In most dialects, there are two variants of `CASE` - one where each `WHEN` is a distinct boolean expression (as in the OP), with no expression between `CASE` and the first `WHEN`, and one where each `WHEN` is a value expression to be compared to a single expression computed after `CASE`. Your correction seems to mix both forms. Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Are you referring to me or an33sh ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbelieve There was a mistake, I've edited my comment. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CASE WHEN shows error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302644/case-when-shows-error)

Comment: @B.Dick: Is this the complete query, are you using a join? Can `CASE_RK` be `null`? Is `INCIDENT_LIVE` a view? If so, show it.

Comment: CASE_RK is always has value but can be set to NULL. INCIDENT_LIVE  is a table.

Comment: using where only selects the datasets where the condition is met. So you have one observation in Incident_live wiith RK=52080. Case when does not limit the observations, so you get all observation in Incident_live (120), but set 119 of them to null because RK is not 52080. I am not sure what you are triying to achive, but as far as i understand it is not  a syntax problem, but a logical problem...

Answer (score 2):

If it is true that only one record has `INCIDENT_RK = 52080` then the other 119 must be records were `CASE_RK` was `NULL`.  Check for yourself.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (INCIDENT_RK = 52080) THEN NULL
            ELSE CASE_RK
       END AS CASE_RK_NEW
     , CASE_RK as CASE_RK_OLD
FROM [casemgmt4].[ecmdb4].[INCIDENT_LIVE]
```